# XPATH SELECTOR to get the next href element

Tags: jquery, xpath

Dear All,  A newbie to XPATH,

I need an xpath to get the HREF tag after the  span class="on" list item

The HTML structure is below. (sorry the editor wont allow me to post HTML in. Can I do that?)
The image file is here: http://imageshack.us/f/846/xpathselector.png/

Please advise. Thank you very much.
San

Comment: You've tagged your post as jQuery and XPath. Which are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you described it in words...

```
//span[@class='on']/parent::li/following-sibling::li[1]/a
```

but why are you talking about XPath since you're working with JQuery and can use css selectors
?

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am feeding it a program. Sorry Jquery I guess was a wrong tag to add. Many thanks for your solution!